# how can optimize this sql query for being faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

this my sql query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM ClassifiedAd
    WHERE city_id = :city
    AND currency = :currency
    AND price > 100) 

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT c.* FROM 
ClassifiedAd c 
WHERE c.city_id = :city
AND c.currency = :currency
AND (c.price > 100 AND c.price < c.price_last))" 
) l,                    
ClassifiedAd a
LEFT JOIN Picture p ON a.id=p.classifiedAd_id
LEFT JOIN Business b ON b.id=a.business_id
WHERE a.id = l.id 
AND (a.price between :priceDown AND :priceUp) 
AND a.subCategory_id IN (:apartamentList) 
AND a.category_id = :category 
AND a.district_id = :district 
AND a.datePosted > :date 
AND b.status = :bStatus AND a.adStatus = :cStatus AND (b.premium OR b.businessPlus OR b.excellence )
ORDER BY -a.business_id DESC LIMIT :limit
```

I'm working with mysql and jdbcTemplate. 
There is some way to make this query faster? 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Nested `select`, `union`, `join`... Those operations can slow down your query, if you figure out how to avoid these, it will work faster. Usually turning joins into select using `and` can be done easily, you just have to be to be more careful when selecting, there could be duplicate columns.

Comment: Hi, please post EXPLAIN plan and table structure including indexes. Indeed nested SELECTs and UNION are generally slower. JOINs can be very fast of indexed correctly.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.  You may be missing some indexes.

Comment: The second part of the UNION seems to be a subset of the first.  If so, get rid of the second part.